# What is the name for this documentation syntax?

Tags: javascript

In the [Material UI docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/radio-button), among others, I see callback functions described like this:

```
function(event: object, value: undefined) => void
```

I know of JSDoc, but I do not know this more terse format, like Flow annotations combined with ES6 arrow function syntax. What is it called?

Comment: It's not JavaScript. It might be Typescript or Flow-annotated JavaScript.

Comment: Not the typescript, Typescript return type is prefixed with : not arrow

Comment: Arrow functions? https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2015/javascript-lambda-and-arrow-functions/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Ah, yes, Flow. It seems very similar to Flow syntax, but not exact. This is flow: `function square(n: number): number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a set of [*React* components](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/required-knowledge), This signature is for *FlowJS*:

[Flow Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-function-types)

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I was looking at the wrong section of the Flow docs. I was looking at actual function implementations rather than formal function specifications.